# H3 getting started

Tags: indexing, maps, geospatial, h3

I'm new to geospatial indexing and found H3 to be really interesting. Currently messing around with the several different functions on API, but my question is how do I render the H3 cells to a map?

What map do you suggest, and how do I go about it?

Kind regards,

Mo

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends partly on what version of H3 you're using - JS, Python, Java, etc. In general, the easiest way to render H3 cells is to use `h3ToGeoBoundary` to get each cell as a polygon, then encode this as GeoJSON or a similar standard format and load that in your map (which could be a web map like Leaflet or MapboxGL, or an application like QGIS, or some other rendering library).

- You can see rendering approaches using MapboxGL in the [H3 tutorials on Observable](https://observablehq.com/collection/@nrabinowitz/h3-tutorial)
- In Javascript, you can use the [geojson2h3](https://github.com/uber/geojson2h3) library to more easily convert between H3 and GeoJSON